# Convert SQL DISTINCT with ORDER BY DESC to LINQ To Entities (bind formatted date to ASP.NET DropDownList control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a requirement to populate an ASP.NET DropDownList control with **distinct** dates, in **descending** order, **formatted** as mm/dd/yyyy.

The distinct dates will be pulled from a *datetime* field named **ImportDate** in a SQL Server database table named **Inventory**.

The following SQL statement will pull back the correct data in the correct order and format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), X.DistinctImportDate , 101) AS ImportDate
FROM
(
 SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(DATE, dbo.Inventory.ImportDate)) AS DistinctImportDate 
 FROM dbo.Inventory
) AS X
ORDER BY DistinctImportDate DESC
```

The data access layer for the project is an Entity Framework 5 model which contains an Inventory entity that has an ImportDate property.

What I need to do is *convert* the above SQL to a C# LINQ To Entities query for Entity Framework 5 and *bind* the results to an ASP.NET **DropDownList** control. Any ideas on how best to achieve this?

**Solution:**

Here is the solution I ultimately wound up going with (thanks to COLD TOLD for leading the way). The following method will return the correct data in the correct order and format:

```
    public static List<string> SelectDistinctImportDate()
    {
        using (var dbo = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            //get distinct dates from database in descending order
            var data = (from c in dbo.Inventory
                     where c.ImportDate != null
                     select c.ImportDate ).Distinct().OrderByDescending(c => c.Value);

            //create list of type string to return formatted results and bind to DropDownList
            List<string> s = new List<string>();

            //loop through all datetime objects returned from linq query 
            foreach (DateTime d in data)
            {
                //format each value and add to return object
                s.Add(d.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
            }

            //return the ordered and formatted list of distinct dates
            return s;
        }
    }
```

The method above can be bound to an ASP.NET DropDownList with an ObjectDataSource as follows:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsDistinctImportDate" runat="server" 
    TypeName="MyLibrary.Inventory" 
    SelectMethod="SelectDistinctImportDate">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistinctImportDate" runat="server"
    AppendDataBoundItems="True"
    DataSourceID="odsDistinctImportDate">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: It sounds like you haven't really worked with linq before. Could you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: @ZacBlazic one of the issues I was having was the placement of the order by clause in the linq query - ultimately, moving the order by clause out of the expression and into a lambda *after* the Distinct() method call proved to be the way to get the distinct results sorted properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq it has distinct by extenston with that it can be achived like this

```
var data=(from c in dbo.Inventory 
          select c.ImportDate).Distinct().OrderByDescending(c=>c.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think this fully solves the OP's problem.  This is just the conversion step; he needs it to actually be connected to the database, and then to populate a combo box.

Comment: Well he need to provide more info in order to get help with that

Comment: @COLDTOLD - thanks, you're answer has lead me in the right direction. A few items... (1) in the OrderByDescending(c=>c.ImportDate) clause the c.ImportDate is unavailable - I had to use c.Value -- (2) the linq expression returns the correct data but not in the correct order (I swapped Distinct and OrderByDescending for the fix) and the format needs to be mm/dd/yyyy (a list of datetime objects will display with a time stamp). I wound up looping thru the list returned from the linq expression and converting each datetime to a string with the proper format. I will update OP with solution.